# Problem linking program with multiple libraries

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a library called `libdarph.a`. I created it using

```
lib/libdarph.a: $(OBJS)
    mkdir -p ./lib
    ar qc $@ $^
    ranlib @
```

I also need two other libraries (`libqhullstatic_r.a` and `libqhullcpp.a`), located in a subdirectory different from `./lib`, which I compiled previously using another makefile:

```
./src/qhull/lib/libqhullstatic_r.a:
    make -C ./src/qhull/

./src/qhull/lib/libqhullcpp.a:
    make -C ./src/qhull/
```

One of the files in `$(OBJS)`, needed in `libdarph.a` uses code based on `libqhullcpp.a` and `libqhullstatic_r.a`. Therefore I compiled it using:

```
./src/DichotomicSearch.o: ./src/qhull/lib/libqhullstatic_r.a ./src/qhull/lib/libqhullcpp.a
    $(CCC) $(CCFLAGS) -c -I./inc/ -I./src/qhull/ -L./src/qhull/lib -lqhullcpp -lqhullstatic_r -lm ./src/DichotomicSearch.cpp -o ./src/DichotomicSearch.o
```

I don't have any problems creating the library `libdarph.a`. But when I want to use it, to create a binary, e.g.

```
binary: $(BINARY_SRC) 
    $(CCC) $(CCFLAGS) $(BINARY_SRC) -I./inc/ -I./src/qhull/ -L./lib -L./src/qhull/lib -lqhullcpp -lqhullstatic_r -ldarph -lm -o $(BINARY_EXE)
```

I receive the following error:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: ./lib/libdarph.a(DichotomicSearch.o): in function `DichotomicSearch::test_3()':
/home/gaul/ownCloud/VSProjects/dynamic-e.-b.-milp/./src/DichotomicSearch.cpp:102: undefined reference to `orgQhull::Qhull::Qhull()'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/gaul/ownCloud/VSProjects/dynamic-e.-b.-milp/./src/DichotomicSearch.cpp:102: undefined reference to `orgQhull::Qhull::~Qhull()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can't make any sense of why `orgQhull::Qhull::Qhull()` is not found (it is included in `libqhullcpp.a`), because I included the flags `-lqhullcpp` and `-lqhullstatic_r` in the lines where the object `DichotomicSearch.o` is created.

Does someone know how to change my Makefile to make this work? Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: If `libdarph.a` uses `libqhullcpp.a` then `libqhullcpp.a` needs to be listed after `libdarph.a` in the linker command

Comment: Firstly there is no point in using linker options when you are only compiling, so remove `-L` and `-l` from your compilation commands e.g. `./src/DichotomicSearch.o: ./src/DichotomicSearch.cpp
    $(CCC) $(CCFLAGS) -c -I./inc/ -I./src/qhull/  ./src/DichotomicSearch.cpp -o ./src/DichotomicSearch.o`

Comment: Secondly the order of the libraries in your actual link is wrong. `libdarph.a` needs to be before the libraries it references. If you have cyclic references then you can list a library twice.